# Finding variance list of lists python

Tags: python, variance

I am new to python, and I need help with finding average and variances in a list of lists.
I have a list of lists like this:

```
data = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9],
        [10, 11, 12]]
```

and I want to find the variances output like this:

```
[var_column_1, var_column_2, var_column_3, var_column_4]
```

I am able to find the average but for the variances, I have no luck on finding a solution. Here is my code:

```
def avg(allgroups):
    return [float(sum(i))/len(i) for i in zip(*allgroups)]
def variance(allgroups):
    summm = 0.0
    for i in zip(*allgroups):
        summm = summm + (i-avg(allgroups))**2
    return summm / (len(allgroups)-1)
    TheAvg=avg(allgroups)
    print(TheAvg)
    Variance=variance(allgroups)
    print(Variance)
```

I keep getting the screen error:

```
*summm = summm + (i-avg(allgroups))**2
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'tuple' and 'list'*
```

I will be grateful for any help. 
P/S: I can't use numpy for this problem.

Comment: why are you using `zip`? Are your groups `[1,2,3]..` or `[1,4,7,10]`?

Comment: my group will be [1,2,3]

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to reinvent the wheel - [`statistics.variance`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.variance) could do the heavy lifting for you:

```py
import statistics

data = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]
variances = [statistics.variance(l) for l in zip(*data)]
```

Comment: I think it is `for l in zip(*data)`

Comment: @DaniMesejo yup, that's right - I misread the requirement. Thanks for noticing, edited and fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the built-in library `statistics` ([documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html)).

```
import statistics

data = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]

def avg(all_groups):
    return [statistics.mean(i) for i in zip(*all_groups)]

def variance(all_groups):
    return [statistics.variance(i) for i in zip(*all_groups)]

print(avg(data))
print(variance(data))
```

Answer (score 1):

The one liner approach without importing statistics:

```
def variance(allgroups):
    return [sum((x - sum(group) / len(group)) ** 2 for x in group) / (len(group) - 1) for group in zip(*allgroups)]
```